# Windows - Icons leaving a blank colmn

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, desktop

I just got a new monitor for my Windows 10 machine, when I try to arrange my icons with fit to grid enabled it leaves a blank column like this:
[image]

If I try to drag anything into that blank space where the third column should be, it either snaps it back to the fourth column, or leaves it there but pushes whatever is in that row's first column down. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: have you tried right clicking your desktop -> View -> Align icons to grid?

Comment: Here's a screen shot https://i.imgur.com/2KjUquO.png.... But uncheck the **Auto arrange icons** option too

Comment: @Bungicasse McDonald's Thanks for the tips, I have so far tried it with both those settings on and off, as well as one off and the other on.

Comment: Something very similar happened when I got a new monitor as well.  I went from a 1080p to 4k screen, that was also larger in length.  Every time the screen put itself to sleep, when it woke up, something like this happened, and I wasn't able to put icons in that column as well  Using one of the arrange options did fix it for me though, but doing this every time my screen woke up was annoying.  I think one day an update to Windows happened, and now it doesn't do it anymore.  See if you're up to date?

Answer (score 0):

So, I wish I had a more concrete answer to offer, but I restarted my machine (for another reason actually) and when I did so the issue was fixed. It may have just been a setting that was crossed up, the restart seems to have fixed whatever was going on.